# How to use the href link feature as well as pass a Django url to a view in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

If I have an `<a>..</a>` Element which has a link it points to , but i also want to call a Django View when it's clicked ,how do i do it?

```
<td ><a href="{{ page.url }}"  >Click Here</a>
```

But i also want to call 'updateViews' in /views.py like this

```
<td ><a href="{% url 'updateViews' page.title %}"  >Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay just found out I could just use onclick for this :

```
<td ><a href="{% url 'updateViews' page.title %}"  onclick="window.open('{{page.url}}');" >Click here</a></td>
```

Comment: You should *not* update items with a GET request, you should use a POST, PATCH or PUT request for this.